# Kotlin data class - conditional copy?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have data class in Kotlin:

```kotlin
data class Foo(a: String, ...)
```

I would like to make a copy of it with `a` changed only if some conditions are met.

something like:

```kotlin
foo.copy( a = if(sth){ "baz" } else { this.a } )
```

but I can't refer to the `foo` object itself inside the copy function.

Comment: I do not really understand the problem there, because in your example, changing `this.a` with `foo.a` works. Can you provide an example with more context please ?

Comment: "but I can't refer to the foo object itself inside the copy function" Why not?

Comment: You have also a missing `var / val` keyword before `a: String`.

Comment: Use apply before doing a copy `foo.apply { copy(bar = if(cond) baz else bar) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data class Foo(var a: String)
```

You cannot use call have self reference directly inside copy fucntion. You can use scope functions like [with](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html) to achieve it.

```
val foo1 = Foo("Hello")
var foo1Copy = with(foo1) {
    copy(a = if (this.a =="Hello") "Hello Again" else "Not Hello" )
}
println(foo1) //Foo(a=Hello)
println(foo1Copy) // Foo(a=Hello Again)


val foo2 = Foo("Hi")
var foo2Copy = with(foo2) {
    copy(a = if (this.a =="Hello") "Hello Again" else "Not Hello" )
}
println(foo2) //Foo(a=Hi)
println(foo2Copy) //Foo(a=Not Hello)
```

[Playground Link](https://pl.kotl.in/nNv-hMwOn)

Hope it helps.